# How to get the user email from auth.User when filterring a field in UserProfile?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a situation where i need to query the UserProfile model but need to get for every user record a field from the auth.User model:

```
groups_list = User.objects.filter(status__in=group_list).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Where "status" in the filter is from the UserProfile model.

Can any one help me with this?

Thank you,

Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) is what you need.
Thus it'll be something like:

```
groups_list = User.objects.filter(userprofile__status__in=group_list).values_list('email',    flat=True)
```

Comment: So simple, This is the part of the "MAGIC" I sometimes lose in python/django. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserProfile` model make sure that the foreign key to `User` has `related_name='profile'` set. You can then do the following:

```
groups_list = User.objects.filter(profile__status__in=group_list).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the other one was much simpler. but thank you very much :-)